# Run sql file for a specific derby database

Tags: sql, connection-string, derby

Using the `ij` tool and Apache Derby, is it possible to execute an sql file in a single command line?

In other words, is it possible to supply the connection string to ij?

At the moment I'm doing it with several steps:

```
java org.apache.derby.tools.ij
connect 'jdbc:derby://someserver:1527//databases/timesheets';
run 'my_file.sql';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run ij using properties, see examples [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/tools/ttoolsij30600.html).

Use the following command:

```
java -Dij.database="jdbc:derby://someserver:1527//databases/timesheets" org.apache.derby.tools.ij my_file.sql
```